# Unable to access string from class

Tags: java, android, json, api

I want to show string from another string in my MainActivity, but the string is getting printed in console. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button start;
    public TextView showText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showText=  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);


        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               RetrieveFeedTask click1 = new RetrieveFeedTask();

                click1.execute();
                showText.setText(click1.getString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the class:

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    static final String API_URL = "http://numbersapi.com/random/trivia?json";

    private Exception exception;
    public String finalString;

    protected void onPreExecute() { }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(API_URL );
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((finalString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(finalString).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            }
            finally{
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(response == null) {
            response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
        }
        try {
            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
             finalString = object.getString("text");

            Log.i("Here",finalString);

        } catch (JSONException e) { 
        }

    }
    public String getString() {
           return  this.finalString;
    }

}
```

Comment: you are never executing the task. I recommend you read more tutorials.

Comment: The asynctask runs on a different thread. Currently, you are setting the string before the task completes. Set the string in `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: I think that when you click the button to start the task, the task doesn't have time to set `finalString` before you set it in the `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

You require the finalString before it's populated with your data. the `onPostExecute` is executed after the `doInBackground` so you should pass your text view to your task and set it's value in the `onPostExecute`

```
    public TextView showText;
    public RetrieveFeedTask(TextView showText) { this.showText = showText; }
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(response == null) {
            response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
        }
        try {
            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
             finalString = object.getString("text");

             showText.setText(finalString ); // add this
            Log.i("Here",finalString);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `showText.setText(click1.getString());` of your activity is called earlier than `finalString = object.getString("text");` of your task.

**Solution:**

Create an interface:

```
public interface DataCallback {
  void onNewData(String data);
}
```

and implement it in your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ... implements DataCallback

public void onNewData(String data) {
  showText.setText(data);
}
```

Pass the interface to your asynctask when you create it:

```
RetrieveFeedTask click1 = new RetrieveFeedTask(this);
```

Call the interface inside the task in `onPostExecute()` to notify the activity that there is new data:

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
finalString = object.getString("text");

callback.onNewData(finalString);
```